# How to get string from hex on Smart Contracts results

Tags: contract-development, web3js, string, console, bytes32

On a Smart Contract called "mem" there is a function called "get()" that returns a bytes32 that is supposed to be a string. How can I decode the string? The result is an hex value. I have tried toString() on geth console, but I am probably doing something wrong...

> mem.get();
>   "0x4d61726b65745061792e696f206973206465706c6f79696e6720536d61727420"
>   mem.get().toString();
>   "0x4d61726b65745061792e696f206973206465706c6f79696e6720536d61727420"
>   mem.get().toString('hex');
>   "0x4d61726b65745061792e696f206973206465706c6f79696e6720536d61727420"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `web3.toAscii(hexString)` as documented in [Web3 JavaScript Ðapp API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii):

```
> web3.toAscii("0x4d61726b65745061792e696f206973206465706c6f79696e6720536d61727420")
"MarketPay.io is deploying Smart "
```

You can also use `web3.toUtf8(hexString)`:

```
> web3.toUtf8("0x4d61726b65745061792e696f206973206465706c6f79696e6720536d61727420")
"MarketPay.io is deploying Smart "
```

Comment: Thx. It works like a charm!

Comment: For version 1.x, it's under `web3.utils`. So you need to do `web3.utils.toAscii(hexString)`