# sendTransaction "code":-32602,"message":"too many arguments, want at most 1"

Tags: contract-invocation, json-rpc

I have a contract that has a function:

```
function addRequest(uint256 d) {
    ...
}
```

After compile and deployment, I typed the command below to call it:

```
curl 192.168.241.128:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{
                "from": "0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1",
                "to": "0x8bed67280f46cc1ffd401cdb3dd5909f254c8f34", 
                "data": "0x4ca1fad8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022b"
            }, "latest"],"id":1}'
```

the first 4 byte of data is the first 4 byte result of web3.sha3('addRequest(uint256)'), and then the a uint32 value 555 padded to 32 bytes. I don't think it is wrong.But it shows me the  result below:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"too many arguments, want at most 1"}}
```

I need a hand, so can anyone help me to solve the puzzle? thank you very much with all my heart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `eth_sendTransaction` only takes one argument, but you are providing two. You should not pass on the value "latest" since this is meaningless for this function. This should work:

```
curl 192.168.241.128:8545 -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{ "from": "0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1", "to": "0x8bed67280f46cc1ffd401cdb3dd5909f254c8f34", "data": "0x4ca1fad8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000022b" }],"id":1}'
```

Comment: [Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21588) if it helps somebody :)